# I can't select the text on my website, I think it's masked by some css

Tags: css, text

Could someone take a quick look, why the text in the dark grey isn't selectable.

I think it's masked by a invisible layer or somewhat, but I don't see it.

The url:

http://www.coldcharlie.nl/test/

Edit: I think it's the shadow part, I'll take a look at that first.

Comment: on the plus side, by solving this you've accidentally worked out how most javascript modal dialogue boxes work :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your test is being overlapped by:

```
<div id="shadow">
  <!-- This is the shadow part -->
</div>
```

Using either Chrome or FireFox + FireBug, you have a right click + **Inspect Element** option that's great for cases like this, I recommend either combination.

Comment: @Chris - Almost forgot, to fix, change `div#shadow { z-index: 100; }` to `-1`, works fine here.

Comment: that was indeed also a option. The container for the shadow image was way to big, by making the div smaller in height, the text was selectable again :)

Answer (score 1):

> The user-select CSS property controls whether the user can select
>   text.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

If the text is not overlapped by an element look for this in your CSS.

```
user-select: none;
```